# Sequelize getter not called when I use find

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have getters defined within the property definition of my model, they look like this:

```
timeReported: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
      get() {
        const input = this.getDataValue('timeReported')
        const output = moment(input).valueOf()
        return output
      },
      set(input) {
        var output = moment(input).toDate()
        this.setDataValue('timeReported', output)
      },
      validate: {
        isBefore: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      }
    }
```

I have tried adding the getter to `getterMethods` in the `options` instead of within the `property`:

```
getterMethods: {
  timeReported: function () {
    debugger
    const input = this.getDataValue('timeReported')
    const output = moment(input).valueOf()
    return output
  }
}
```

I find that the setters are executed correctly when I save because I use timestamps as the request payload. I also find that validations work correctly.
Interestingly the `afterFind` hook is called correctly and it does show that `customGetters` have been registered as existing on my model.

However, when I call the `find` method on my model like this:

```
const {dataValues} = yield models.Reporting.findOne({
  where: {
    reportNo: reportNo
  }
})
```

My `getter` methods are not invoked to transform my data for presentation. How do I invoke these methods on the data fetched from the db before I can access it.

I have tried adding the `raw:false` property to the `queryOptions` along with `where`. That did not work.

**NOTE**: I fetch my data using `co`, I have to retrieve the `dataValues` property from the model. None of the examples seem to be using the property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Sequelize,one should not use `dataValues` property directly as I did. This will give me access to the underlying data stored in the table without invoking the `getters`.

To invoke all the getter functions on the entire instance:

```
const data = instance.get()
```

This will also populate any `virtual` fields that one has defined in the model.
To invoke the `getter` for an individual property:

```
const propValue = instance.get('timeReported')
```

Comment: As of Sequelize 5 it seems like calling the getter on the property itself is required. In Sequelize 4 calling `.get()` would invoke all getter functions. Now we must call `.get('timeReported')` (see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/9568).